# Render Game World Smaller Than Screen Width and Height

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, screen, viewport

I am currently working on a LibGDX mobile game app. The problem I am having is that I want the world width and height to be 480x480 and the screen width and height to be 640x480. The extra 240 units on the screen would be used for rendering UI, kind of like in ROTMG or Clash Royale(The cards view while in game).

I have thought about rendering the UI over the game with another camera, but it is not the design style I am going for. I want the game's logic and coordinates to be within the world's width and height and not take in the extra space for UI.

How would I do this?

P.S. the game is 2d

P.P.S. I would like for the game to keep this config on resize.

Answer (score 1):

Denfeet, create a fullscreen Stage with 2 Group instances - one of them for UI, the other for the game. Groups: Game's bounds are 0, 0, 480, 480. UI's bounds are 480, 0, 240, 480. Now if you want to work in coordinates relative to the game Group for example, call Group.localToStageCoordinates(Vector2 localCoords) on the game Group (or make yourself a helper method so you don't have to keep writing this long name). Also the UI and game logic can stay completely separated this way - magic :-).

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't think about that! I will look more into the Group class, but in theory if you say I can do this with groups would it be easier to just create a second stage, or is this more efficient? Thanks

Comment: WonderfulWorld, I looked more into groups and saw that you can set a culling area, but I still dont understand how to make the camera and player centered in this group. Im not asking for code examples (unless you can), but could you please elaborate on the helper class you suggested

Comment: Well, you should definitely stick to 1 Stage at a time if at all possible. Let's just say unless you're a fan of completely rewriting your code over and over, this will retain the most flexibility for you. The camera is centered on the Stage, not either Group, but this is beside the point as you just need to lay out your game Group correctly. The helper method is useful only if you're excessively calling Group.localToStageCoordinates(), if you use Group.addActor(), the Actor's bounds will automatically work relative to the Group's coordinates (Actor) position 0, 0 is the Group's 0, 0. Continue

Comment: Continue-> I suggest you just try out the above, it's in line with the flow of the library. As a final note - a more general tip, I'd suggest torturing any framework you're using as little as possible and just going along with its flow - usually things work the way they do for a reason (which can be a bad reason). You'll find that whenever you go against the spirit of the framework, you're unravelling this endless thread which makes you waste more and more time to keep your code working - that's when you'll usually find that if you want to add a feature, it's easier to rewrite from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I always like to separate my game from UI. You can just create a camera full screen and put your UI over it with a Scene2D stage. Unless you want the exact dimensions you don't have to worry to much about positioning since you just overlay your UI elements. If you want to use a stage for your game as well then just create a 2nd stage, one for the game and one for the UI.

Anyway, looks like you are thinking in pixels. Your game does not need to know about pixels, just how much to render of your game world. If I would have a tile that is `10 x 10` units large and I want to show a square of `10x10` tiles to the player I would create a `new FitViewport(100, 100)` for it. The `Viewport` calculates world units back to pixels on the device it is running. This makes things more logical for you or anyone who works on your program. My player is not `256 pixels` high because that is how hight the image is, no my player is `1,80m` high and uses a image to display. If he wants to jump like a ninja he should jump over another player say `2m` and he falls at `9.8m/s`.